# Change the default colour palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written a function that returns a vector of color names:

```
custom.colors <- function(n) {
  palette <- c("dodgerblue1", "skyblue4", "chocolate1", "seagreen4",
               "bisque3", "red4", "purple4", "mediumpurple3",
               "maroon", "dodgerblue4", "skyblue2", "darkcyan",
               "darkslategray3", "lightgreen", "bisque",
               "palevioletred1", "black", "gray79", "lightsalmon4",
               "darkgoldenrod1")
  if (n > length(palette))
    warning('palette has duplicated colours')
  rep(palette, length.out=n)
}
```

I would like ggplot to use the above function to generate the palette by default. Maybe only for discrete scales. Using `scale_manual()` every time is too much of a drag. Is it possible?

Comment: [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2-dev/browse_thread/thread/fc838059c281e835?pli=1) should be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that for later, but now I'm stuck with version 0.8.9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@baptiste pointed me to a message board post that mentions the function `set_default_scale` which can be used to set a default palette. The following solution only works with old versions of ggplot2, though.

First we need a function that produces colour names or codes. I called mine `magazine.colours`:

```
magazine.colours <- function(n, set=NULL) {
  set <- match.arg(set, c('1', '2'))
  palette <- c("red4", "darkslategray3", "dodgerblue1", "darkcyan",
               "gray79", "black", "skyblue2", "dodgerblue4",
               "purple4", "maroon", "chocolate1", "bisque3", "bisque",
               "seagreen4", "lightgreen", "skyblue4", "mediumpurple3",
               "palevioletred1", "lightsalmon4", "darkgoldenrod1")
  if (set == 2)
    palette <- rev(palette)
  if (n > length(palette))
    warning('generated palette has duplicated colours')
  rep(palette, length.out=n)
}
```

(It accepts an optional `set` argument just to show that you are not restricted to a single palette.) Ok, now we create a "scale", which I called `magazine`. It's based on ggplot's brewer scale and the code is pretty ugly:

```
ScaleMagazine <- proto(ScaleColour, expr={
  objname <- 'magazine'
  new <- function(., name=NULL, set=NULL, na.colour='yellowgreen',
                  limits=NULL, breaks = NULL, labels=NULL,
                  formatter = identity, variable, legend = TRUE) {
    b_and_l <- check_breaks_and_labels(breaks, labels)
    .$proto(name=name, set=set, .input=variable, .output=variable,
            .labels = b_and_l$labels, breaks = b_and_l$breaks,
            limits= limits, formatter = formatter, legend = legend,
            na.colour = na.colour)
  }
  output_set <- function(.) {
    missing <- is.na(.$input_set())
    n <- sum(!missing)
    palette <- magazine.colours(n, .$set)
    missing_colour(palette, missing, .$na.colour)
  }
  max_levels <- function(.) Inf
})
scale_colour_magazine <- ScaleMagazine$build_accessor(list(variable = '"colour"'))
scale_fill_magazine <- ScaleMagazine$build_accessor(list(variable = '"fill"'))
```

The important thing here is to define `output_set` which is the function that ggplot calls to get the colour names/codes. Also, if you need extra arguments, those must be included in `new` and later can be accessed as `.$argument_name`. In the example above, `output_set` simply calls `magazine.colours`.

Now, check the new scale does actually work:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, shape=21,
      colour=factor(carb), fill=factor(carb)) +
  scale_colour_magazine(set='1') +
  scale_fill_magazine(set='1')
```

To make it the default, simply use `set_default_scale`.

```
set_default_scale("colour", "discrete", "magazine") 
set_default_scale("fill", "discrete", "magazine")
```

And that'll be it.

```
> qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=factor(carb), fill=factor(carb))
```

[image: plot showing the new palette]

Answer (score 29):

17 days ago (2020-05-19) [work by Carson Sievert has been merged](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/3833) into the development version of ggplot2 that allow to specify the default discrete color palette(s) with an option (`ggplot2.discrete.fill` & `ggplot2.discrete.colour`):

```
options(ggplot2.discrete.colour= c("red", "#af01ef"))
```

It also allows to specify several palettes of different size (with the smallest sufficient palette being used):

```
options(ggplot2.discrete.colour= list(c("red", "#af01ef"), custom.colors(99)))
```

It does not take a palette function (like your `custom.colors`) but it does take a scale function - so you could build one to produce the warning that you want:

```r
# `custom.colors` defined as in question
scale_custom <- function(aesthetics, scale_name= "custom", ..., palette = custom.colors) discrete_scale(aesthetics = aesthetics, scale_name, ..., palette = palette)
scale_colour_custom <- function(...) scale_custom("colour", ...)
options(ggplot2.discrete.colour = scale_colour_custom)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y= Petal.Length, color = Species)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Width, y= Petal.Length, color = factor(Sepal.Length))) + geom_point()
#> Warning in palette(...): palette has duplicated colours
```

[image]

From the [NEWS](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> Default discrete color scales are now configurable through the `options()` of
> `ggplot2.discrete.colour` and `ggplot2.discrete.fill`. When set to a character
> vector of colour codes (or list of character vectors)  with sufficient length,
> these colours are used for the default scale. See `help(scale_colour_discrete)`
> for more details and examples (@cpsievert, #3833).

Comment: I had to use the spelling "colour" to make it work: `options(ggplot2.discrete.colour = c("red", "#af01ef"))`

Comment: yes, thanks! (some insights into this problem: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4626)

Comment: If anyone wants to see how to extend the above solution to different scales and palettes, worth looking at this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68205270/4083743) too

Comment: @user63230 thanks, I expanded to the custom scale section to include one such example that actually allows to use a custom palette *function*.

Answer (score 21):

To redefine the default color scale you can also just redefine the `ggplot` function:

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```

The same works for the fill scale.

Comment: Simple and beautiful.

Comment: that'll likely cause trouble when you map a continuous variable to colour

Answer (score 6):

Simply assign a variable with the name of your desired scale:

```
scale_colour_discrete <- function(...)
  scale_colour_manual(..., values = c('dodgerblue1', *))
```

This works since ggplot will take its default scales from the global environment if possible, similarly to:

```
get('scale_colour_discrete', envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: I could not get it working. Could you provide a working example?

Comment: In an interactive R session, depending if you want to use a scale for discrete or continuous values, and depending on if you want it for colour or fill, you have to define a variable called `scale_{colour,fill}_{discrete,continuous}`, e.g. `scale_colour_discrete <- scale_colour_viridis_d; ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point()`

Comment: Note: This only works if code is executed in the global env. If ggplot2 code is used within a function environment, this won't work.