# is there a way to change the color palette for GGally::ggpairs using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, palette

I would like to change the color palette for the `GGally` function `ggpairs`.  When I attempt to add ggplot commands to the ggplot returned using `getPlot`, the colors do not change.

```
my_pair_plot = ggpairs(dataset, color="var1")
getPlot(my_pair_plot,2,1) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

Attempting to put ggplot commands directly on the `ggpairs` function results in an error.

```
ggpairs(dataset, color="var1") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out, this is possible! It requires looking up the source code, but the solution comes up pretty easily. We are interested in `ggpairs` function, so the first step is just

```
ggpairs
```

Let's see if we can find any aes mapping to fill or colour. Indeed,

```
combo_aes <- addAndOverwriteAes(aes_string(x = xColName, 
            y = yColName, ...), section_aes)
```

We may hope it does what it says. Two important notes:

- colour and fill aes should be contained in the ellipsis for the `ggpairs` call
- `aes_string()` is used

Let's try this out:

```
ggpairs(diamonds[, 1:2], colour='cut')
```

[image]

Excellent, we're almost there! We just need to override the colour palette. Note that something like you propose

```
ggpairs(diamonds[, 1:2], colour='cut') + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

will not work because ggpairs object is not a ggplot, so the `+` notation is not directly applicable in any way. However, the simple workaround is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504724/change-the-default-colour-palette-in-ggplot?). Cross your fingers, and...

```
ggplot <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
ggpairs(diamonds[, 1:2], colour='cut')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## update:

GGAlly was updated again and the hack in this answer *also* doesn’t work anymore, but finally there’s a non-hack solution: given

```
scales <- scale_colour_brewer(type = 'qual') %+% scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual')
```

you can do (in a hopefully future-proof way)

```
for (row in seq_len(ps$nrow))
    for (col in seq_len(ps$ncol))
        ps[row, col] <- ps[row, col] + scales
```

## old way

The hack in the other answer does not work anymore, so let’s hack a new one!

The internal structure of a `ggpairs` object is the dataset and a list of strings:

```
> dta <- data.frame(a=1:6, b=7:12, c=c('f', 'g'))
> ps <- ggpairs(dta, 1:2, colour = 'c')
> str(ps)
List of 10
 $ data        :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ a: int [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ b: int [1:2] 3 4
  ..$ c: int [1:2] 5 6
 $ columns     : int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ plots       :List of 9
  ..$ : chr "ggally_densityDiag(ggally_data, ggplot2::aes(x = a, colour = c))"
  ..$ : chr "ggally_cor(ggally_data, ggplot2::aes(x = b, y = a, colour = c))"

[...]

 $ gg          : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggpairs"

> ps
```

[image: plot before]

In order to modify the plot, the respective strings in the plot object need to be modified to include the additional command. For this, we use `deparse(substitute(argument))` to get a string containing the code the user passed, and append it to every plot call:

```
add_to_plots <- function(pairs, modification) {
    str <- deparse(substitute(modification))
    pairs$plots <- lapply(pairs$plots, function(s) paste(s, '+', str))
    pairs
}

> add_to_plots(ps, scale_colour_brewer(type = 'qual'))
```

[image: plot after]

Comment: This does not work anymore either. I'd like to have the density plots in the diagonale not filled but as lines as shown here - how do I do this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727408/how-do-i-have-the-density-plot-not-filled-in-ggallyggpairs

Comment: This changes the colors, but not the fact that my plot is still filled.

Comment: that’s pretty trivial, just overwrite the fill.

Comment: Sounds trivial, but I was not able to get it done, because the question remains: With what? I tried `NULL`, but that does not work. I don't want something else there - I want it transparent.

Comment: you’re right. usually that’s `waiver()` but it doesn’t seem to work. and i can’t find where the `aes(fill)`/`scale_fill_*` is added…

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the most non-hacky way to change the palette is to modify its own graphing function since they return ggplot2 objects which can be customized freely.

To change the density in the diagonal, just change the corresponding function, `ggally_densityDiag`.

```r
modified_density = function(data, mapping, ...) {

  ggally_densityDiag(data, mapping, ...) + scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2")
}
```

Then, provide the new function to `ggparis` function call, as below,

```r
ggpairs(iris, columns = 1:3,  aes(color = Species),
        diag = list(continuous = modified_density))
```

[image]

There are `upper` and `lower` arguments that can be used for other parts of the plot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the matrix plot to a variable and then iterating through each plot with a for-loop also seems to do to the trick:

```
library(GGally)

plot.matrix <-ggpairs(iris,aes(color= Species), upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size=6)))

for(i in 1:5) {
  for(j in 1:5){
    plot.matrix[i,j] <- plot.matrix[i,j] +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
  }
}

plot.matrix
```

Example is modified from Schmuller (2018): *R Projects for dummies*, p. 149.

[image]