# Set alpha and remove black outline of density plots in ggpairs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

Consider this example:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape")
library(GGally)
pm <- ggpairs(tips, mapping = aes(color = sex), columns = c("total_bill", "time", "tip"))
pm
```

[image]

How do I make the density plots more transparent and remove the black lines?

The `GGally` packages seems to have changed a lot recently and I cannot find a working solution

**update**

I found how to change the alpha with a custom function:

```
my_dens <- function(data, mapping, ..., low = "#132B43", high = "#56B1F7") {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping=mapping) +
    geom_density(..., alpha=0.7) 
}

pm <- ggpairs(tips, mapping = aes(color = sex), columns = c("total_bill", "time", "tip"),
              diag=list(continuous=my_dens))
pm
```

but the black line still remains.

Comment: Have you checked [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/vignettes/ggpairs.html)? Particularly, play with the examples in "Matrix Sections" / "Custom functions" or "Plot matrix subsetting" and show us your attempts.

Comment: You are almost there! Just set `color` to `NA` to get rid of the lines. `my_dens <- function(data, mapping) {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5, color = NA)
}`. In your case, the `low` and `high` arguments are redundant, because you don't use `scale_fill_gradient` (as they do in the example). Feel free to write up your "update" as an answer.

Comment: @Henrik perfect, thanks

Comment: @Henrik that vignette link is broken, but [saved at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320034441/cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/vignettes/ggpairs.html) ... also  [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727408/edit-individual-ggplots-in-ggallyggpairs-how-do-i-have-the-density-plot-not-f/34853734#34853734)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thanks to @Henrik this is the solution using a custom function

```
my_dens <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  ggplot(data = data, mapping=mapping) +
    geom_density(..., alpha = 0.7, color = NA) 
}

pm <- ggpairs(tips, mapping = aes(color = sex), columns = c("total_bill", "time", "tip"),
              diag = list(continuous = my_dens))
pm
```

[image]

Examples on how to customize `ggpairs` plots can be found in [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/vignettes/ggpairs.html). See the "Matrix Sections" and "Plot Matrix Subsetting".

Comment: I know the answer if over one year old, but it does not seem to be working any longer. When I copy paste your code, I just get blank densitys.

Comment: Try to use fill instead of color.

Comment: @MLEN this answer worked for me -- [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727408/edit-individual-ggplots-in-ggallyggpairs-how-do-i-have-the-density-plot-not-f/34853734#34853734)

Comment: but the density curves are not filled anymore, in my case

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
pm <- ggpairs(tips, mapping = aes(color = sex, alpha = 0.7), columns = c("total_bill", "time", "tip"))
```

Comment: this is the way

Comment: I seems like setting `alpha` inside `aes` just toggles it on/off. If you use `wrap` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019969/2166823 you can set `alpha` to the actual value you specify.