# ggpairs displaying density functions as unfilled lines

Tags: r, ggally

I am hoping to just change the diagonal plots to have simple outlines so I can view the overlap of the density functions more clearly but am not having much luck. Here is the code I have been using:

```
plot_rh <- ggpairs(data_rh[,1:6],  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = Condition_name),
lower = list(combo = wrap(ggally_facethist, bins = 10)), 
diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag"), mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill=Condition_name)))
```

Plot with filled density functions:

[image: Plot with filled density functions]

Comment: Sorry about that...this was my first time posting a question. Would this be more appropriate "How to specify unfilled lines using ggpairs?"

Comment: What's lacking is the data to reproduce your problem. But in fact, the question could be closed as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727408/edit-individual-ggplots-in-ggallyggpairs-how-do-i-have-the-density-plot-not-f

Answer (score 1):

Changing `aes(fill=Condition_name)` to `aes(color=Condition_name)` should result in unfilled lines.

You could also change it to `aes(fill=Condition_name), alpha = 0.4` to make the filled densities semi-transparent which may improve the view.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, however, after changing 'fill' to 'color' it still is filled, but the alpha does improve viewing the density functions.

Comment: Interesting; I had assumed that `aes()` would work as for `geom_density` but apparently not. Anyway: this question has been asked before and has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727408/edit-individual-ggplots-in-ggallyggpairs-how-do-i-have-the-density-plot-not-f