# How to change the color palette for GGally::ggpairs?

Tags: r, ggally

This is the same question as in
[User defined colour palette in R and ggpairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237783/user-defined-colour-palette-in-r-and-ggpairs) or [is there a way to change the color palette for GGally::ggpairs using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711550/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-palette-for-ggallyggpairs-using-ggplot)

only that the solutions there don't work anymore.

---

I also want to change the color palette, but [is there a way to change the color palette for GGally::ggpairs using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711550/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-palette-for-ggally-ggpairs-using-ggplot) does not work anymore. What to do?

MWE:

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1],200),]
ggpairs(
  diamonds.samp[,1:2],
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), combo = "box"),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3), combo = wrap("dot", alpha = 0.4)),
  diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag")),
  title = "Diamonds"
)
```

[image]

I would like to add

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue','green','red','blue'))
```

(obviously that is just dummy code) and get something like (I did not paint over all the dots):

[image]

Comment: Please don't be so lazy and provide at least an MVE.

Comment: @Pascal: Sorry, forgot a line. Please try again.

Comment: What is your expected output? Because I get colored figures with your code.

Comment: @Pascal: Of course :-). I would like to *change* the colors that are set automatically. I give a (very ugly) example.

Comment: Still not clear how it is (was) supposed to work.

Comment: @Pascal: If you run the code you see in the MWE, you get the first plot. I am sure that you get that plot as well, right? The colors here are red, some-sand-yellow, green, blue, mangenta, right? I want to change theses colors. For the example I don't care to which colors. An example would be 'red','blue','green','red','blue'. I am not sure where the example is unclear.

Comment: This will **not** be the way to do it, *but it is a way* ...  just overwrite each plot in the matrix... `for(i in 1:2) {
  for(j in 1:2){
    p[i,j] <- p[i,j] + scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black")) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"))
  
  }
}`

Comment: @user20650: I had a similar solution (even a bit more ugly), before it broke with the new version of GGally. I guess your solution is good enough for me: Iit won't get more elegant than that. If you like, please put it as an answer.

Comment: okay done. There must be a way to do this within ggpairs, but i am not at ll familiar with it.... so good enough

Comment: @user20650: I don't think there is. GGally is very hard to configure - you always ends up hacking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One solution is to extract each plot from the `ggmatrix` add a new `scale_` and then reassign it back to the matrix.

Example

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1],200),]

p <- ggpairs(
  diamonds.samp[,1:2],
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), combo = "box"),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3), combo = wrap("dot", alpha = 0.4)),
  diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag")),
  title = "Diamonds"
)
```

Loop through each plot changing relevant scales

```
for(i in 1:p$nrow) {
  for(j in 1:p$ncol){
    p[i,j] <- p[i,j] + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black")) +
        scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"))  
  }
}

p
```

To give

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding directly both `+ scale_fill_manual` and `+ scale_colour_manual` after your `ggpairs` code will work also:

```
ggpairs(
  diamonds.samp[,1:2],
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = cut),
  upper = list(continuous = wrap("density", alpha = 0.5), combo = "box"),
  lower = list(continuous = wrap("points", alpha = 0.3), combo = wrap("dot", alpha = 0.4)),
  diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag")),
  title = "Diamonds") +    
    scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','blue','green','red','blue')) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue','green','red','blue'))
```