# Can you set ggplot palette for entire Rmd?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

When I create an Rmd report I can use `theme_set()` to set the theme for all figures in my Rmd report. Can I do something similar to set a certain ggplot palette for the entire Rmd report?

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [change the default color palette in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10504724/903061)