# How to set ggplot global color themes using RColorBrewer palettes

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, colorbrewer

I am trying to set up a global ggplot2 color scheme in my global RMarkdown files and I had success with `viridis` with the following code

```
options(
  ggplot2.continuous.colour = "viridis",
  ggplot2.continuous.fill = "viridis"
)
scale_colour_discrete = scale_colour_viridis_d
scale_fill_discrete = scale_fill_viridis_d
```

However, when I try to use a similar procedure with RColorBrewer, I was unable to do so with default color still showing up. What changes should I make for it to work?

```
options(
  ggplot2.continuous.colour = "brewer",
  ggplot2.continuous.fill = "brewer"
)
scale_colour_discrete = scale_colour_brewer(palette="Dark2")
scale_fill_discrete = scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Discrete

If you wish to specify a default, discrete colour scale such as that produced by `scale_colour_brewer()` use the `ggplot2.discrete.colour` option. Similarly, use the option `ggplot2.discrete.fill` for a discrete fill scale.

### Default Discrete Scales

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Custom Discrete Scales

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale_colour_brewer_d <- function(..., palette = "Dark2") {
  scale_colour_brewer(..., palette = palette )
}

scale_fill_brewer_d <- function(..., palette = "Dark2") {
  scale_fill_brewer(..., palette = palette)
}

options(
  ggplot2.discrete.colour = scale_colour_brewer_d,
  ggplot2.discrete.fill = scale_fill_brewer_d
)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

## Continuous

If you wish to specify a default, continuous color scale, you will need to use `scale_colour_distiller()` instead of `scale_colour_brewer()`. Similarly, use `scale_fill_distiller()` as opposed to `scale_fill_brewer()` for a continuous fill scale. You will also use the options `ggplot2.continuous.colour` and `ggplot2.continuous.fill` respectively.

### Default Continuous Scales

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = cyl, fill = cyl)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### Custom Continuous Scales

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale_colour_brewer_c <- function(..., palette = "Dark2") {
  scale_colour_distiller(..., palette = palette )
}

scale_fill_brewer_c <- function(..., palette = "Dark2") {
  scale_fill_distiller(..., palette = palette)
}

options(
  ggplot2.continuous.colour = scale_colour_brewer_c,
  ggplot2.continuous.fill = scale_fill_brewer_c
)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, color = cyl, fill = cyl)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer is perfect!