# Changing the default color of the histogram bars in ggplot for all the code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the default colour of the histogram bar in ggplot, the same way I change the theme using theme_replace at the beginning of my code.

Is that possible ?

I tried to follow this post : [Change the default colour palette in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504724/change-the-default-colour-palette-in-ggplot/62216465#62216465)

```
df = data.frame("Group" = c("A", "B"), "Value" = c(7, 11))

options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = c("red", "blue"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Value)) + geom_histogram(stat = "identity")
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and code?

Comment: I think this question is clear even without code, but also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62216465/8400969

Comment: I edited my post, I tried to follow the link you gave but I couldn't make it work.